# Fitting large tables

Tags: tables, landscape, supertabular

I need to fill the appendix of my work (I am using `scrbook`) with a lot (more than 100) of large tables. This is the end of a long work by a group of people. The tables were done in Microsoft Word in a A4 landscape format, and I need to import them without re-writing the all thing. As a first thing I converted them using the write2latex extension of Libreoffice. An excerpt of the output is shown below (there is only one table, here, of will not be not in a landscape format and the only solution I found is to rotate them of 90°. Therefore, I inserted a `minipage` environment to rotate each table, hoping that it will suffice to fit them into the page.
Can you think of any better solution?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Text styles
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.7cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{2022-01-01}
\begin{document}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{Standard}

\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{4.007cm}|m{6.7130003cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Zhang Y\textit{ et al. }Laparoscopic versus open incisional and
ventral hernia repair: a systematic review and meta-analysis. World Journal of Surgery 2014}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}

 \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
~

\textbf{Disegno dello studio:} Systematic Review e Meta-analisi di RCTs

~

\textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

Moderata

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi}: Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting}: Ernie ventrali primitive o incisionali

\textbf{Finanziamenti}: Nessuno

\textbf{Tassi di dropout}: Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni:}

{}- Eterogeneità clinica dovuta a definizioni differenti e tecniche operatorie differenti

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale primitiva o ernia ventrale incisionale

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }\ {}-- Luglio 2013

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi non-randomizzati, studi focalizzati su altri tipi di ernia, duplicati} &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.291cm}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Carbajo 1999, Moreno-Egea 2002, Misra 2006, Barbaros 2007, Olmi
2007, Navarra 2007, Pring 2008, Asencio 2009, Itani 2010, Eker 2013, Rogmark 2014}\\\hline
\textbf{Outcomes} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria

{}- Infezione di ferita

{}- Lesioni intestinali

{}- Sieroma post-operatorio

{}- Ematoma post-operatorio

{}- Occlusione intestinale

{}- Sanguinamento

{}- Reintervento

~
 &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }11 studi randomizzati con arruolamento totale di 1003 pazienti (501
nel gruppo laparoscopico e 502 nel gruppo open

{}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.21, 95\% CI 0.77-1.91 (P= 0.41)

{}- \textbf{Infezioni dei ferita:} RR = 0.19, 95\% CI 0.11-0.32 (P{\textless} 0.00001)

{}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali:} RR = 3.68, 95\% CI 1.58-0.67 (P= 0.003)

{}- \textbf{Sieroma post-operatorio: }RR = 0.99, 95\% CI 0.46-0.10 (P= 0.97)

{}- \textbf{Ematoma post-operatorio:} RR = 0.94, 95\% CI 0.53-0.65 (P= 0.82)

{}- \textbf{Occlusione intestinale:} RR = 1.58, 95\% CI 0.55-0.58 (P= 0.40)

{}- \textbf{Sanguinamento:} RR = 1.88, 95\% CI 0.41-0.71 (P= 0.42)

{}- \textbf{Reintervento:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.16-0.09 (P= 0.07)}\\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{flushleft}
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: it really isn't clear what you want here you are using very low level direct length settings to set a landscape page (better just to use `\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}`) but however you do it the page orientation is wider than it is tall so you do not need any rotation of the table as far as I can see.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Comment: Maybe you could use  the `sidewaystable` environment ( `rotating` package) in the place of `minipage` + rotation.

Comment: Since you mention "The tables were done in Microsoft Word in a A4 landscape format, and I need to import them without re-writing the all thing": Why don't you simply export the word file to pdf and include the pdf file into your tex file as an image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I was not clear. My fault. The code here is in a landscape orientation (the direct length settings belong to the Libreoffice output, Ill try to remove them. The point is that I have to move the table to a portrait oriented larger `scrbook` document. At that point the table (larger than tall) will not fit and will need to be rotated.

Comment: @leandriis because the word documet is very long (at the end there will be more than 100 tables) and it is in a landcape orientation. The final document will be in a portrait orientation. If I export the word document in pdf I will obtain 100 pages landscape oriented.

Comment: you can use the lscape or pdflscape packages to rotate a multi-page table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more solution with `tabularray` package with combination of the `enumitem` and `etoolbox` package.

**Edit:**
For percentage of value is used `siunitx` package (instead of `95%` is used `\qty{95}{\%}` which gives typographically nicer result). Also are changed `(P= 0.97)` and similar expressions to `(P = 0.97)` or for example to \mbox{(P = 0.09)} etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
\setlist[description]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=2em,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={X[l,h] *{3}{X[1.5,l,h]}},
             row{2}= {font=\bfseries, f},   % <---
             measure = vbox,                % <===
             }
\SetCell[c=4]{l, wd=\linewidth}    \textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} 
    Meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials comparing open and 
    laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. 
    British Journal of Surgery  2009.   
    &   &   &   \\
Disegno dello studio
Livello di evidenza  
    &   Dettagli dello studio/limitazione 
        &   Caratteristiche dei pazienti
            &   Interventi              \\
    \begin{description}
\item[Disegno dello studio:]    Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs
\item[Certezza delle prove:]    Bassa
    \end{description}
    &   \begin{description}
    \item[Paesi:]   Non applicabile
    \item[Centri:]  Non applicabile
    \item[Setting:] Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali
    \item[Finanziamento:]       Non riportato
    \item[Tasso di dropout:]    Non applicabile
    \item[Limitazioni:] ?
    \item[Critical appraisal:]  AMSTAR II
        \end{description}
        &   Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale
            \begin{description}
        \item[Ricerca bibliografica:] Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009
        \item[Criteri di inclusione:] Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti 
        la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi
        \item[Criteri di esclusione:]   Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione 
        di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi
            \end{description}
            &   Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. 
            a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi  \\
\textbf{Note}: 
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{l}  \textbf{Studi inclusi:} 
    Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
    Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008   \\
\textbf{Outcomes} 
    &   \begin{itemize} 
    \item   Recidiva erniaria
    \item   Durata dell'intervento chirurgico
    \item   Durata dell'ospedalizzazione
    \item   Tempo di ritorno a lavoro
    \item   Sieroma
    \item   Complicanze emorragiche
    \item   Lesioni intestinali
    \item   Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi
    \item   Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi 
        \end{itemize}
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{l, wd=0.54\linewidth}  \textbf{Risultati:}
            8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 
            nel gruppo open.
            \begin{description}
        \item[Recidiva erniaria:] RR = 1.02, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.41-2.54 (P = 0.97)
        \item[Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:] Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
        \item[Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:] Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
        \item[Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:] Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati
        \item[Sieroma:] RR = 1.22, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.38-3.99 (P = 0.74)
        \item[Complicanze emorragiche:] RR = 0.42, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.11-1.54 (P = 0.19)
        \item[Lesioni intestinali:] RR = 1.95, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.38-9.85 (P = 0.42)
        \item[Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi:]  
            RR = 0.22, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.09-0.54 \mbox{(P = 0.001)}
        \item[Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi:] 
        RR = 0.32, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.08-1.22 \mbox{(P = 0.09)}
            \end{description}   
            &   \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Solution with classic tables' packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}% <---
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
\setlist[description]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=2em,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize 
                       \RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
                        

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| L{0.7} | *{3}{L{1.1}|} }
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.}
    Meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials comparing open and
    laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh.
    British Journal of Surgery  2009}   \\
    \hline
Disegno dello studio\par
Livello di evidenza
    &   Dettagli dello studio/limitazione
        &   Caratteristiche dei pazienti
            &   Interventi              \\
    \hline
    \begin{description}
\item[Disegno dello studio:]    Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs
\item[Certezza delle prove:]    Bassa
    \end{description}
    &   \begin{description}
    \item[Paesi:]   Non applicabile
    \item[Centri:]  Non applicabile
    \item[Setting:] Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali
    \item[Finanziamento:]       Non riportato
    \item[Tasso di dropout:]    Non applicabile
    \item[Limitazioni:] ?
    \item[Critical appraisal:]  AMSTAR II
        \end{description}
        &   Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale
            \begin{description}
        \item[Ricerca bibliografica:] Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009
        \item[Criteri di inclusione:] Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti
        la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi
        \item[Criteri di esclusione:]   Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione
        di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi
            \end{description}
            &   Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs.
                a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi  \\
    \hline
\textbf{Note}:
    &   \multicolumn{3}{L{3.3}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:}
    Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
    Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008}   \\
    \hline
\textbf{Outcomes}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   Recidiva erniaria
    \item   Durata dell'intervento chirurgico
    \item   Durata dell'ospedalizzazione
    \item   Tempo di ritorno a lavoro
    \item   Sieroma
    \item   Complicanze emorragiche
    \item   Lesioni intestinali
    \item   Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi
    \item   Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi
        \end{itemize}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{L{2.2}|}{\textbf{Risultati:}
            8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253
            nel gruppo open. 
            \begin{description}
        \item[Recidiva erniaria:] RR = 1.02, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.41-2.54 (P = 0.97)
        \item[Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:] Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
        \item[Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:] Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
        \item[Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:] Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati
        \item[Sieroma:] RR = 1.22, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.38-3.99 (P = 0.74)
        \item[Complicanze emorragiche:] RR = 0.42, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.11-1.54 (P = 0.19)
        \item[Lesioni intestinali:] RR = 1.95, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.38-9.85 (P = 0.42)
        \item[Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi:]
            RR = 0.22, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.09-0.54 \mbox{(P = 0.001)}
        \item[Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi:]
        RR = 0.32, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.08-1.22 \mbox{(P = 0.09)}
            \end{description}}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

As you can observe, in table design need more manual tweaks as in the first MWE. Result is similar as before:

[image]

However, this with some additional effort can be done with ˙tabular*`or even`tabular` too, however, determination of columns and multi-columns widths at them is a bit more challenging.

**Off-topic**
I guess that your document is in portrait orientation (as they are usually are). In this case only the tables due to their width) to be in the `landscape` orientation. This can be done by use of the `sidewaystable` environment defined in the `rotating` package (for one page long tables) or by use of `landscape` environment defined by `lscape` or `pdflscape` packages. Which is more appropriate depends from your document structure.

Comment: It looks very nice; however, apparently my system does not have `tabularray`. I read it is part of LaTeX3: is it possible that my TeXlive distribution (on Ubuntu) does not have it? Should I install it?

Comment: @FabioCampanile, the `tabularray` is relative new package, based on LaTeX 3 project, but is not a part of it. Therefore it may not be a  part of your TeXLive installation. It is available on CTAN. I'm not familiar with Ubunto nor with TeXLive, so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Now, I have it installed. Certainly, your table looks the most appealing for my output. The question is:  is there a way to change all my tables in this format or I would need to rewrite the all thing? Looks as shifting from `tabular` to `longtblr` takes a lot of manual input. Second question: how can I pur colors in the cells?

Comment: @FabioCampanile, I'm afraid that editing of your tables require some manual work. If the table code in your question is result of conversion from word to  LaTeX should be done anyway (if you like to have beautiful tables), so if in this you also make conversion to `tabularray` is not so much additional work. Result in my answer can be obtain also with "classic" tables' packages, for example with `tabularx` but code is less elegant and simple. The way of use of `itemize` and `description` stay the same as in answer.

Comment: I did the conversion from word with the Libreoffice extension Writer2latex that produced an output I had to modify. However it is easy, for example, to change all `supertabular` into `tabular`, much more difficult to completely change the cell structure. I have to change some 100 tables

Comment: @FabioCampanile, I add a solution with use of the `tabularx` table. However, its use require a bit more works as at use of `tabularray` package. If you prefer only to change `supertabular` to `tabular`, than both answers are not what you are willing to do with your tables. Sorry.

Comment: No, I am sorry, I did not explain myself. I only said that with more than 100 tables to fit in the document, I would prefer to be able to do some simple editing of the code I got from the conversion (for example using the function "replace" to change one sequence to another) rather than editing each single table by hand. I really would like to do it with the `tabularray` that looks excellent, but it seems to me that the structure of the table is rather different (for example it uses `\setcell` instead of `multicolumn`.

Comment: Besides, for some reason, when I insert `\usepackage{tabbularray} in my document, I get an error message that says that it cannot find the file ninecolor.sty (that I have no idea what it is)

Comment: It is part of `tabularray` bundle. If you load package by some wizard, it should be automatically loaded. Otherwise you need to load tool, It contain definitions of  colors for tables.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `tabularray` package to create any type of table.

Here two tables are added. One is by using `tblr` environment (counterpart of `tabular`), another one using `longtblr` environment (counterpart or `longtable`).

Using `tblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{%
    hlines, vlines,
    width = \textwidth,
    colspec={X[1, c, m] *{3}{X[2, c, m]}},
    row{2}={font=\bfseries},
    }
    \SetCell[c=4]{l, wd=\textwidth}\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery 2009. & & &\\
    Disegno dello studio Livello di evidenza & Dettagli dello studio/limitazione & Caratteristiche dei pazienti & Interventi\\
    
    \textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs

~

\textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

Bassa

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}:

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

~
 &
Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\

\textbf{Note}: &
\SetCell[c=3]{l, 0.8\textwidth}\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008 &&\\

\textbf{Outcomes} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria

{}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico

{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione

{}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro

{}- Sieroma

{}- Complicanze emorragiche

{}- Lesioni intestinali

{}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi

{}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
\SetCell[c=2]{l, 0.55\textwidth}\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
gruppo open.

{}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati

{}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)

{}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)

{}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)

\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `longtblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
        caption = Table caption,
        label = tab_longtable1
    ]{%
        hlines, vlines,
        width = \textwidth,
        colspec={X[1, c, m] *{3}{X[2, c, m]}},
        row{2}={font=\bfseries},
    }
    \SetCell[c=4]{l, wd=\textwidth}\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery 2009. & & &\\
    Disegno dello studio Livello di evidenza & Dettagli dello studio/limitazione & Caratteristiche dei pazienti & Interventi\\
    
    \textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs

~

\textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

Bassa

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}:

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

~
 &
Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\

\textbf{Note}: &
\SetCell[c=3]{l, 0.85\textwidth}\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008 &&\\

\textbf{Outcomes} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria

{}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico

{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione

{}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro

{}- Sieroma

{}- Complicanze emorragiche

{}- Lesioni intestinali

{}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi

{}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
\SetCell[c=2]{l, wd=0.57\textwidth}\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
gruppo open.

{}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati

{}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)

{}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)

{}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)

\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

1st page:
[image]

Next page:
[image]

**Notes:**

- The package `geometry` was used to change the page layout into landscape. See [this article](https://texblog.org/2007/11/10/landscape-in-latex/) for more on landscape.
- Notice that to shift from `tblr` to `longtblr`, one doesn't need to change the content in the environment which makes it more easy to shift.
- The table should work fine in `scrbook` also.